# Blender VSE camera input?

Tags: camera, video-sequence-editor

beginner user here.

I've animated a scene in blender, switching between spots in the scene with camera markers. I want to add a wipe effect from one shot to the other, and it seems I should be able to use the VSE for this.

But when I put a strip into the sequencer and choose camera input, there is no image.

I've tried looking at tutorials but haven't found anyone with the same question. I have the sequencer ticket in post processing, I've looked through the input options and chosen the right cameras, so why isn't anything coming up the VSE preview?

Is it or isn't it possible to use the active camera as input for a scene? Or do I need to render everything into a video and just edit that?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Since you're in Preview > Scene Strip Display > Material, my guess is you need to add a light in the scene. If you change the display to Solid do you get an image?

Comment: Sadly, I've tried adding a light, or change the display to wireframe, solid, etc. 
It changes nothing. :(